# Are extra files in my project compiled into my program?

Tags: iphone

Lets say I have a bunch of PSD's and other large files that arent being used in my xCode project... Do those get added to the app when I compile? Do I need to store those somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, they will be included.  If you don't want that, then do the following:

1. In the Xcode project window, select all the resources you don't want included.
2. Hit the big blue *i* button on the toolbar.
3. Go to the Targets tab.
4. Uncheck your app's target.

Incidentally, this also works if you have a code file you don't want compiled in.

Comment: The comment about code is true, and quite handy for Full/Lite versions of an app, just have 2 targets.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can remove them from your target's "Copy Bundle Resources" if you don't want them in your .app file.

Comment: I think he /wants/ them to be included in his project.

Comment: I thought he wanted them in his project but not in his app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure, go to your build directory and open the .app package and see if the files are in there.  Right-click on it in the Finder and choose "Show Package Contents"